# How to print out objects in an array by passing in a single Base object while accounting for object slicing?

Tags: c++

Say I have something like this:

```
int main()
{
    Base *array[2];

    array[0] = new Base("Hello", 2);
    array[1] = new Derived("Bye", 3, 5);

    DisplayEverything(array[0]);
    DisplayEverything(array[1]);

    cout << endl << "Deleting...." << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        delete array[i];
    }
}
```

and a non-member function that prints the Base and Derived objects:

```
void DisplayEverything(Base* a)
{
    a->print();
}
```

In both Base and Derived classes, I have setup a virtual destructor and a virtual print function like: virtual void print();

```
void Base::print()
{
    cout << a << " " << b << endl;
}
```

and:

```
void Derived::print()
{
    cout << get_a() << " " << get_b() << " " << c << endl;
}
```

This would do what is expected, but is there any way I can pass an object instead of a pointer instead? I'd like the function to be something like this:

```
void DisplayEverything (Base a)
{   
    a.print();
}
```

How would I do something like this?

I am not sure why it's not possible because I have done it once, but I ran into object slicing problem, here is what I had:

```
Base *array;
array = new Base [2]; 
array[0].set_info("Hi", 1, 2); 
DisplayEverything(array[0]);
```

with the DisplayEverything function now as this:

```
void DisplayEverything (Base a) 
{ 
a.print(); 
}
```

Comment: Where are you learning C++ from? Why would you "like" to pass an object by value into that function?

Comment: Why would you want to pass a (new) object if you want the behavior from the existing object?  If it’s syntax you want, pass a reference.

Comment: I want to know if it's possible. It seems more logical to me to be passing in an object itself instead of sending a pointer. I am still a beginner, so I don't really understand how it works.

Comment: @nc052: You can’t _ever_ pass “an object itself” (note for experts: prvalues are not objects, anymore), only a copy of it, a pointer to it, or a reference to it.

Comment: @DavisHerring But isn't it possible to pass an object itself if I make an array such as this: Base *array; array = new Base [2]; Then, manually set the values such at this: array[0].set_info("Hi", 1, 2); and DisplayEverything(array[0]) with the function as this: void DisplayEverything (Base a)
{   
    a.print();
}

Look at editted question with the correct format.

Comment: @nc052 -- You're looking for Java, not C++.

Comment: @nc052: Even with an array of `Base` objects (not pointers), you **copy each one** in passing “it” to `void DisplayEverything(Base)`.

Comment: `void DisplayEverything(Base &a)` works with the original code, but you cannot have an array of `Base` that store `Derived`. You need to keep using the array from the original code

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, some guidelines:

1. Do not use raw pointers for memory management. Use smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr`. In Modern C++ `new` and `delete` should almost never appear in your source code.
2. Do not use inheritance unless you have a clear extensible hierarchy of things sharing the same interface. `std::variant` might be more appropriate for your use case (and has value semantics).
3. Do not use C-style arrays, prefer `std::array` from the `<array>` header.

---

> is there any way I can pass an object instead of a pointer instead?

If you want virtual dispatch at run-time through polymorphic inheritance, the answer is no. You need to pass either a pointer (`std::unique_ptr` if owning) or a reference.

If you want the dispatch to happen at compile-time, you can use a template:

```
template <typename T>
void DisplayEverything (T a)
{   
    a.print();
}
```

Alternatively, if you want run-time dispatch with value semantics for a closed set of types, use `std::variant`.

Comment: Handy reading explaining some of the terms used above: [What is dispatch? Does it imply dynamic resolution?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/224684/what-is-dispatch-does-it-imply-dynamic-resolution)